# Windows web app wrong start up page

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications

I am creating a windows web app on visual studio. When launched, I need the web browser to start up with the login page but it doesnt, it starts up on a different page. Anyone know why? or how to remedy the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Henks answer looks like what you want, but if you are using ASP.NET MVC? you could tag your controllers/methods with the [Authorize] attribute. This would redirect users that is not logged in to the login page (or any other page should you decide to override the defaults).

Comment: Correct, and probably the better way to get the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your project's properties page (right-click on project, select properties).
2. Go to the "Web" tab
3. Change the "Start Action" to your login page.

I'm guessing that at the moment your setting is to open the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your web.config file, in this way you could indicate the default page, something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <remove value="default.aspx"/>
    <remove value="index.html"/>
    <remove value="index.htm"/>            
    <add value="Login.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```